# Visual Basic файл используется другим процессом

Tags: visual-basic

Всем доброго времени суток.

Пищу программу, которая архивирует содержимое папки.

Проблема:

> "result.zip - файл используется другим процессом"

Код:

```
 Dim startPath As String = "c:\example\start"
 Dim zipPath As String = "c:\example\result.zip"

 ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath)
```

Нагуглил решение похожей проблемы через Thread. Воткнул код в поток, но это не помогло. 
Подскажите, куда смотреть?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему переносом архива в другую папку.

```
Dim startPath As String = "c:\example\start"
Dim zipPath As String = "c:\example2\result.zip"

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath)
```